# "Bug: unable to handle kernel paging request at" while installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have an old laptop Sony Vaio vgn-s580p that has install problems with 12.04.3 and 13.04.

I have tried using the WUBI as well as burning an ISO directly for both versions. Any way I try to install it I get an error that is just white text on black with nothing that I understand.

Are there any known problems with this laptop and Ubuntu? Is it just too old to run?

Here's the gobbeldegook:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! It was just an issue of configuring the boot options with nomodeset.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: Exactly what you configured?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that iso files you've got aren't right. Validate them here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Also, you will need at least 512MB RAM to be able to run Ubuntu properly https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: I just verified hashes also using winMD5sum. Everything matches up.

Answer (score 0):

don't worry, your laptop is not a problem to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 and 13.04.
make sure that your HDD partitions are primary partition for destination installation drive.
 may be your ISO file ahve some missing files. Better try to install Ubuntu  with the help of USB Pendrive.
steps:
1.download free ubuntu OS image file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download
2. make pendrive bootable by using "LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8.23" tool. its free and run the file.
3.sellect drive -> choose ISO/IMG file -> assign PERSISTENCE -> format the key in FAT32 -> Click lightning icon to create bootable.
4. then restart your system.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the BIOS doesn't support booting from USB. There are no BIOS updates sadly.